# TensorFlow and word embeddings - TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I wish to modify the code at http://www.brightideasinanalytics.com/rnn-pretrained-word-vectors/, which is about predicting the next word, to have code that predicts answers to questions.

Here is an excerpt of the code I'm having trouble with:

```
import tensorflow.contrib as ct

def NHIDDEN():
    return 1

g = tf.Graph()
tf.reset_default_graph()

with g.as_default():
    # lines 97-104 of original code
    # RNN output node weights and biases
    weights = { 'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([NHIDDEN(), embedding_dim])) }
    biases = { 'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([embedding_dim])) }

    with tf.name_scope("embedding"):
        W = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[vocab_size, embedding_dim]),
                    trainable=False, name="W")
        embedding_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [vocab_size, embedding_dim])
        embedding_init = W.assign(embedding_placeholder)
        preimage = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, x2)

    # lines 107-119 of original
    # reshape input data
    x_unstack = tf.unstack(preimage)

    # create RNN cells
    rnn_cell = ct.rnn.MultiRNNCell([ct.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(NHIDDEN()), ct.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(NHIDDEN())])
    outputs, states = ct.rnn.static_rnn(rnn_cell, x_unstack, dtype=tf.float32)

    # capture only the last output
    pred = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out'] 

    # Create loss function and optimizer
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.l2_loss(pred-y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

    # lines 130, 134 and 135 of original
    step = 0
    acc_total = 0
    loss_total = 0

    with tf.Session(graph = g) as sess:
        # lines 138, 160, 162, 175, 178 and 182 of original
        while step < 1: # training_iters:
            _,loss, pred_ = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict =
                                 {x: tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, x2), y: tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, y)})
            loss_total += loss
            print("loss = " + "{:.6f}".format(loss_total))
            step += 1
        print ("Finished Optimization")
```

The error I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7a72d8d4f100> in <module>()
     42         while step < 1: # training_iters:
     43             _,loss, pred_ = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict =
---> 44                                      {x: tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, x2), y: tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, y)})
     45             loss_total += loss
     46             print("loss = " + "{:.6f}".format(loss_total))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

How do I fix the code? Is it because of `unstack`ing?

Additional context: `x2` and `y` are assigned the return value of `np.array(list(vocab_processor.transform([s])))` where `s` is a string (by passing different strings). `embedding_dim`, `vocab_size` and `W` are computed using the code at https://ireneli.eu/2017/01/17/tensorflow-07-word-embeddings-2-loading-pre-trained-vectors/.

Comment: Always show the full traceback with the error message--otherwise it's hard to understand where the error message comes from.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Sorry, you make a good point. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs here: `y: tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, y)`. The `feed_dict` keys should be placeholders from the TensorFlow graph. Assuming that `y` is a `numpy.ndarray` containing the target values, you could define a [tf.placeholder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) `y_` to feed the target values into the network, changing the corresponding entry of `feed_dict` to `y_: tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, y)` and modifying the other tensors accordingly (i.e. use tensor `y_` to compute the loss).