# TensorFlow and word embeddings: passing a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Similar to [TensorFlow and word embeddings - TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448897/tensorflow-and-word-embeddings-typeerror-unhashable-type-numpy-ndarray), I want to pass values to the `feed_dict` part of `sess.run()`. Why do I get the same error about an unhashable type when I'm also using `reshape`, as well as `flatten` (I didn't observe these differences before compared to the code at http://www.brightideasinanalytics.com/rnn-pretrained-word-vectors/)?

```
sent_toks = nltk.sent_tokenize(ctxt)
x2 = np.array(list(vocab_processor.transform(sent_toks)))
y = np.array(list(vocab_processor.transform(<some other string>)))

import tensorflow.contrib as ct

def NHIDDEN():
    return 1

def NINPUT():
    return 50

g = tf.Graph()
tf.reset_default_graph()

with g.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph = g) as sess:
        while step < 1: # training_iters:
            x2 = np.reshape(np.array(x2.flatten()), [-1, NINPUT()])
            y_embedding = np.reshape(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, y), [1,-1])
            _,loss, pred_ = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict =
                                 {x2: x2, y: y_embedding})
            loss_total += loss
            print("loss = " + "{:.6f}".format(loss_total))
            step += 1
        print ("Finished Optimization")
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ecd566e6a457> in <module>()
     51             y_embedding = np.reshape(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, y), [1,-1])
     52             _,loss, pred_ = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict =
---> 53                                      {x2: x2}) # , y: y_embedding})
     54             loss_total += loss
     55             print("loss = " + "{:.6f}".format(loss_total))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried to understand the details of your code, but do see what to me looks like a problem with your usage of the feed-dict. The syntax for feed_dict is that the key is a tensor in the tf-graph - typically a `tf.placeholder`, while the value is the data you want to feed to it. Here x2 is used both as key and value, which is probably the problem. So if `tf_node` is where you want to feed the data, you should use `feed_dict = {tf_node: x2}` and not `feed_dict = {x2: x2}`.

Hope this helps.